# Visible satellites real time position API

Tags: observational-astronomy, positional-astronomy, artificial-satellite

I'm trying to obtain the azimuth and elevation of all (or at least the majority) visible artificial satellites from a given latitude and longitude. Is there a quite stable API that does that for free? I found some APIs that track particular satellite event, ISS passes and so on, but nothing about what I'm looking for.

This should run on an ESP8266 board, so I can't afford to store positions database or a large ephemeris and do to calculations on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've already used the site N2YO.COM and the API. There is a lot of satellites on it and the most important ones.

- https://www.n2yo.com/api/

Comment: Could you add a link to their API document and a brief overview of what it provides?

Comment: Well, I've not used it in a while and from what I've seen here : https://www.n2yo.com/api/ they have changed their system so i won't be able to provide you more infos. Hope that can help !

Comment: I think it is exactly what i was looking for, it's provide a lot of possible request and the limit of 1000 request/hour is very generous, at least for my need. Thank you very much @YoannA.